# php - splitting a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following strings:

```
http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/2053/XM1014-BLAZE-ORANGE-FACTORY-NEW
http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/2053/XM1014-BLAZE-ORANGE-MINIMAL-WEAR
http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/2053/XM1014-BLAZE-ORANGE-BATTLE-SCARRED
http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/117344/STATTRAK-XM1014-HEAVEN-GUARD FACTORY-NEW
http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/117325/STATTRAK-XM1014-HEAVEN-GUARD-WELL-WORN
http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/117330/STATTRAK-XM1014-HEAVEN-GUARD-BATTLE-SCARRED
```

I need to find the last two words - i.e:

```
FACTORY-NEW
MINIMAL-WEAR
BATTLE-SCARED
```

I would like to achieve something similar to this:

```
if ($item == 'FACTORY-NEW') {
    $grade = 'fn';
}
```

Comment: Search for "PHP regex" and try to work out some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another idea:

```
^.*?(\w)\w+\W+(\w)\w+$
```

This way you will have your *two last initial letters* by replacing all by *$1$2*.

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/nH4lC6/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with regex:

```
(?<=-|)([A-Z])[A-Z]+-([A-Z])[A-Z]+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mD4vM8/10)

which means:

- `(?<=-|)` - lookbehind for `-`, so fallowing metacharacter need to be
  preceeded by `-`
- `([A-Z])[A-Z]+-([A-Z])[A-Z]+` - two sets of upper case characters with `-` between,
- `$` - end of a line, so regex match at the end of line, last two words
  you can get the first characters of words with $1$2

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$splitUp = split("-", "http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/2053/XM1014-BLAZE-ORANGE-FACTORY-NEW")
```

Then, take the last two elements of the resulting array and make a new string

```
$newString = $splitUp[count($splitUp)]-1 . "-" . $splitUp[count($splitUp)];
```

That would give you the 2nd to last element, a dash, and the last element as a new string.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Fair enough.  It seemed to me OP was looking for an idea on how to solve the problem.  I tried to provide an idea...  We're all just trying to help here...

Comment: No doubt. I'm trying to help you make your answer *better* :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str ="http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/2053/XM1014-BLAZE-ORANGE-FACTORY-NEW";
$arr=explode("-",$str);
$count=count($arr);
$newStr="";
for($i=$count-2;$i<=$count-1 ;$i++){
    $newStr .= $arr[$i].'-';
 }

 $newStr=rtrim($newStr, "-");
 echo $newStr;
```

You can pass your string to the $str variable at very first line of code dynamic to get your desire results.